# JQuery 'hold' button - toggleClass vs hasClass compatability issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a system that randomly populates several lines of text from a database, but each line has a 'hold' button (like a fruit machine) that holds that line while the others are regenerated - I'm using AJAX to do this and that bit works fine.

```
<div id="hold1" class="rememberthis"></div><div id="line1">Foo</div>
<div id="hold2" class="rememberthis"></div><div id="line2">Bar</div>
etc...
```

I'm using JQuery to toggle the class of the 'hold' button for each line - eg:

```
    $("#hold1").click(function(){
      $('#hold1').toggleClass("lineselected");
    });
```

Then, I am trying to query whether the hold button has that "lineselected" class - as a way of preventing the JQuery AJAX .load function from reloading the content - thus 'holding' that particular line. #recycle is the button that reloads everything.

```
if(!$('#hold1').hasClass("lineselected")){
$('#recycle').click(function(){
    $( "#line1" ).load( "index.php #inline1" );
});
}
```

...but it doesn't work!

The top bit works - the "lineselected" class toggles nicely. Also, if I hard code the hasClass() to something it has on the original load (like "rememberthis"), it works. So the two bits of JQuery work independently... they just won't work *together*...

Anyone ideas where this could be going wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide more context regarding your posted code. How/when do you call it?

Answer (score 0):

It is basically because your element id is "#hold1" not just "hold1".
So $('#hold1') can not find the element.

Comment: JQuery Id selector requires # char. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: Many thanks for the reply Curious Sam - apologies for the confusion - I've edited the question to contain the correct code, without the #'s.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if(!$('#hold1').hasClass("lineselected")){
    $('#recycle').click(function(){
        $( "#line1" ).load( "index.php #inline1" );
    });
}
// probably same code repeats for #hold2, #hold3, etc
```

try

```
$('#recycle').click(function(){
    if(!$('#hold1').hasClass("lineselected")){
        $( "#line1" ).load( "index.php #inline1" );
    }
    // you should repeat for #hold2, #hold3 here
});
```

What it does here is to put the if-check in the click event.

In your original code, `$('#recycle').click` is called multiple times. That essentially bind the click event to `#recycle` multiple times. You probably forgot to unbind these events (and in this case, I don't think it's easy to find out and unbind them...) before your next check. So it does not work.

My answer suggests you to put the condition check in the click event handler, and only bind it once.